# sql 'incorrect integer value' message

Tags: php, mysql, null

Can anyone see why i am getting the following error when i try to submit this? I know the whole null vs '' thing but I don't have any '' that should be causing this. New to mySQL so any help would be great.

Incorrect integer value='' for column 'two' at row 1

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "TEST";

$db_pass = "example";

$db_name = "questions";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No database");


if ($_POST['parse_var'] == "contactform"){


$oneField = $_POST['one'];
$twoField = $_POST['two'];
$threeField = $_POST['three'];
$noneField = $_POST['none'];
$surveyField = $_POST['survey'];
$questionField = $_POST['questions'];
$guestField = $_POST['guest'];
$homeField = $_POST['home'];


$selected_radio = $_POST['radio'];
  if ($selected_radio == 'one') 
  {
  $oneField = '1';
  }

  else if ($selected_radio == 'two') 
  {
  $twoField = '1';
  }

  else if ($selected_radio == 'three') 
  {
  $threeField = '1';
  }

  else if ($selected_radio == 'none') 
  {
  $noneField = '1';
  }


if($surveyField == "yes"){
$surveyField = "1";
 } 
if($mysqlField == "yes"){
$mysqlField = "1";
 } 
if($guestbookField == "yes"){
$guestbookField = "1";
 } 
if($homeField == "yes"){
$homeField = "1";
 } 

$sqlUpdate = mysql_query("INSERT INTO questiondata (one, two, three, none, survey, 
       question, guest, home)
 VALUES  ('$oneField','$twoField','$threeField','$noneField','$surveyField','$questionField','$guestField','$homeField')")
 or die (mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: try to remove the ' in the insert statement, AND initialize all fields to NULL (case doesnt matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to `INSERT` with one of the integer arguments being empty, i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO questiondata (one, two) VALUES ('1','')
```

This will not work unless `one` or `two` are string fields.
Modify your code so empty variables will be initialized:

```
$oneField = isset($_POST['one']) ? $_POST['one'] : 0;
$twoField = isset($_POST['two']) ? $_POST['two'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Column "two" is an integer column, and appearantly you're trying to insert an empty string into that.

Check for empty strings, and replace them with another value or null (if the column is nullable)

```
$twoField = $_POST['two'];
if (empty($twoField))
{
  $twoField = 0;
}
```

PS: I recommend doing this for other fields as well.